# Autotools naming bug

Tags: build, crash, gnu, autoconf

I have following `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_OUTPUT
```

And it generates configure, that contains following lines:(`grep core configure` )

```
1572:  rm -f core *.core core.conftest.* &&
2143:rm -f core conftest.err conftest.$ac_objext conftest.$ac_ext
2210:rm -f core conftest.err conftest.$ac_objext conftest.$ac_ext
2212:rm -f core conftest.err conftest.$ac_objext conftest.$ac_ext
2214:rm -f core conftest.err conftest.$ac_objext conftest.$ac_ext
```

Fun begins with the fact, that I have folder, named `core`. So `./configure` yield

```
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
configure: creating ./config.status
rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
```

I found in google, that it is done in case of compiler crash. But is it any nice way to disable this check(I really do not care about compilers that can core dump on autoconf tests). 
Renaming folder is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is it any nice way to disable this check

No, there isn't.

> Renaming folder is not what I want to do.

In that case, I suggest patching 'configure' after somewhere in an autoconf 'bootstrap.sh' script or after whatever runs `autoreconf`:

```
#!/bin/sh
autoreconf -fvi # or whatever autoreconf needs
sed -i 's/rm -f core/rm -f/g' configure
```

Note that `sed -i` is not a universal solution, as it relies on GNU sed, but it's not too hard to come up with a portable solution.

Comment: Thanks. Moved `core` to `src/core`. I have to respect tradition.

Answer (score 0):

As show in the question most projects have a `configure.ac` file with rules for generating the `configure` script. The last line is almost always `AC_OUTPUT` (as it is in your case). You can add this after that line (usually as the very end of the file) to manipulate the generated configure file and scrub the offending commands:

```
m4_esyscmd_s([test -f configure && sed -i -e '/rm -f/s/ core / /' configure])
```